# How to configure Azure File Storage to access from Windows Service

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, sql-server-agent, file-storage

We are developing and SSIS service to import some data in Excel and CSV files in Azure. For uploading the files we have chosen Azure File Storage and we are running the SSIS packages on a VM. For picking up the files from file storage, we have mapped the File Storage as mapped network drive on the VM. This works file when we manually trigger the SSIS jobs. However, this fails when running as SQL Server Agent job. As far as I understand, the mapped drives are per user and they do not work for service account used for SQL Server Agent. Is there a way by which we can access the file storage in SSIS packages as SQL Agent Jobs?

I found [this page](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_network/windowsservices/article.php/c12357/C-Map-Network-Drive-API.htm) but this is for basic windows network file sharing. Does not work for us as we also need to use the Shared Access Key for Azure File Storage.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem using [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2017/12/01/ssis-packages-executed-through-sql-agent-job-scheduler-fails-while-connecting-to-azure-file-storage-path/) solution.
Add credential via cmd not via the GUI